# Why does my code raise 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013) error?

Tags: python, discord

Thanks for stopping by!

When I run my code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\PC\OneDrive\Namizje\VS CODE\discord-bot\cemess.py", line 22, in reset
    await member.edit(nick=None) # reset their nickname
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 880, in edit
    data = await http.edit_member(guild_id, self.id, reason=reason, **payload)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 738, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1349, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

I am trying to reset nicknames of everyone on a server. I gave the bot administrative permissions and placed it's role on top of the roles list. I am also the server owner. So, what permissions am I missing?

```
import discord.ext
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#', intents = intents)



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')



@bot.command() # command decorator
@commands.has_permissions(change_nickname=True) # check for change nickname permission
async def reset(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members: # loop through every member in the guild
        await member.edit(nick=None) # reset their nickname


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

This is my code. I excluded the token because that's, well private.

I am new to programming and I will be very happy with any kind of help!

edit:

I came up with a new idea:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(change_nickname=True)
async def reset(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Maks')

    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if role not in user.roles:
            continue
        await user.edit(nick=None)
```

The role Maks was given to all users with admin permissions. The code still raises the same error.

Comment: I don't believe you can change the nickname of the server owner, so you need to add a check for that.

Comment: Oh, I have never thought of that. Thank you very much! I will try and make the bot ignore users with admin perms.

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

Comment: that depends on which python lib you are using, there should be able to make an `if` condition with something like `if not member.guild_permissions.administrator:`

Comment: I think I found a way to filter users with admin perms but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of experimenting, I found a cure to my problem. Thanks to Anu6is for help!

code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$#$', intents = intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(change_nickname=True)
async def reset(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Heheheha')

    for user in ctx.guild.members:

        if role not in user.roles:
            continue

        await user.edit(nick=f'{user.name}')

    return
```